# Statistical significance of correlations from confidence intervals... making my brain hurt a little

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval

Quick question (hopefully)...

If you have a correlation of -0.256 with a 99% confidence interval of -0.541 to 0.185,
OR, a correlation of -0.336 with a 99% CI of -0.597 to 0.125...

That essentially translates to a non-significant correlation, right?  At least, not at the p < 0.01 level...

Tell me if I'm getting this wrong, because as I understand it, if the confidence interval includes the null hypothesis (which would be 0.0 for a correlation..?) Then you reject the null hypothesis, right? Which is essentially the same as saying that, in this case, p **>** 0.01.

However, p < 0.01 is stricter than the usually acceptable p < 0.05. So, is it still possible that this above correlation is still significant at p < 0.05, despite not being significant at p <0.01? If so, how could you find out?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that means it is not significant at the 0.01 level.

No, that means you fail to reject the null. If p was less than 0.01 you would reject the null.

And you can test if the correlation is significant at 0.05 by looking at tables, using online calculators, testing in R or SAS or any other statistical program. You will also have to know the sample size.